# Display current article's specific custom field in module

Tags: php, joomla-4.x

Im using Joomla 4. And for some reasons I need to publish my articles with joomla 4 custom html module that shows specific custom fields of current article.
I have changed mod_custom's default.php file like this but coldn't get the value of "engine-1" custom field. I will be so happy if someone could help about it.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\CMS\WebAsset\WebAssetManager;
use Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();

?>

<?php
// Get the custom field values

$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_menus.item', $active, true);
$active->arbitrary_property_name = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $active->arbitrary_property_name[$field->name] = $field->value;
}
?>
<?php
// Output the value of the custom field if it exists
if (isset($active->arbitrary_property_name['engine-1'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . $active->arbitrary_property_name['engine-1'] . "</h1>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Custom field 'engine-1' is not defined or does not exist in the current menu item.</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question 
to show us the output from `var_export($active)`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the hint from here
[Custom Fields inside Articles News Module in Joomla 4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32242/custom-fields-inside-articles-news-module-in-joomla-4)
And made my own module from mod_article_news.

Just kept the codes I need and deleted rest. Than added custom filed part from the topic above like this.

default.php

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Model\ArticleModel;
use Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;

$jinput = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$id = $jinput->getInt('id');

$model = Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Article', 'Site');
$article = $model->getItem($id);

if (!$article) {
    return;
}
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article, true);
$article->arbitrary_property_name = array();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $article->arbitrary_property_name[$field->name] = $field->value;
}
?>

<?php echo $article->arbitrary_property_name['engine-1']; ?>
```

ArticlesNewsHelper.php

```
<?php

namespace Joomla\Module\ArticlesNews\Site\Helper;

use Joomla\CMS\Access\Access;
use Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication;
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Helper\RouteHelper;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseAwareInterface;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseAwareTrait;
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class ArticlesNewsHelper implements DatabaseAwareInterface
{
    use DatabaseAwareTrait;


    public function getArticles(Registry $params, SiteApplication $app)
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getList(&$params)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I don't have php knowledge. Thats why I made it on my own way.